# update Azure Vm Scalset Image to new one

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have created one scalset in azure with custom vm image and now I want to change image refernce of that vm to new one.
How we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below powershell command will help you in updating the VM

```
Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" -ImageReferenceVersion 16.04.201801090
```

and here is the link for complete [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#update-the-os-image-for-your-scale-set) about VMSS Scale set

Comment: I just changed the -ImageReferenceVersion parameter to -ImageReferenceId and it works. Thank you

Comment: Could you please accept my answer as it could be helpful for other community members as well